# Problem with integrated terminal in PhpStorm

Tags: terminal, phpstorm, git-bash

I'm learning Laravel, and also I started learning it with(for me) new editor - PhpStorm. I want to edit my terminal(not colors, fonts, etc.). I integrated the gitbash instead of factory terminal that comes with PhpStorm.

The problem is that I'm having some'? ' with a number, usually '32m' before the statements in my terminal. To explain it better, here's a screenshot:

And for example, everyone that I've seen on google, using PhpStorm have 'normal' editor without those symbols and numbers before each line in the terminal.

My terminal atm :

[image]

Tried searching JetBrains FAQ, googling and ofc here on StackOverflow, but no luck for me.

What would I like my terminal to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh3Vv.jpg

Comment: These codes are the ANSI color codes. But I first need to know if that behaviour happens also by using git bash outside phpstorm or not

Comment: It happens also with the default terminal, but if I go directly to gitbash app/or good old command prompt, everything is fine, only in PhpStorm..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it's missing is the ANSI support for color codes. As a result you see those strange characters as these aren't parsed and therefore displayed as output.

Maybe you could try with a little utility like ansicon. For further details take a look at [this article](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/ansi-color-in-windows-shells) (outdated but might work anyway)

Comment: Sadly, the site is down, cant reach it. Anyway, im gonna google it out about ansicon utility. Ill upvote your answer since that would solve my issue. Thanks a lot once again!